# Tensorflow words to number

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I would like to be able to convert words to numbers. For example:

- one hundred = 100
- one thousand three hundred = 1300
- 35k = 35000
- three grand = 3000

I have found several libraries which do not require machine learning which is able to perform this task with a some level of success such as [words-to-numbers](https://github.com/finnfiddle/words-to-numbers).

Given the variety of words would a machine learning approach yield a better result? If so, what approaches / models would you recommend me to use / study ?

Answer (score 0):

A sequence to sequence model would be one approach:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq

You will need a lot of data. I'd start by creating a generator that creates training examples with the largest variety possible.

I'm not sure how well this will work. It might not even do as well as the library you mentioned. It's worth a try though.